# Is it possible to pass the dimension of a Loader object to another class?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have a class (ImageLoader) that extends Sprite container and loads an external image to its instance. When i instantiate an object of this class from another (Main) class i want to have the dimensions (width, height) of the loaded image being known to this (Main) class. It seems that is difficult for me as the dimensions are known after the image compete loaded. But i don't know how to pass this information from completeHandler event handler to the Main class. Any ideas?

`package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;`

```
public class Main extends Sprite
{       
    private const img1:String = "pic1.jpg";
    private const img2:String = "pic2.jpg";

    private var myImg1:ImageLoader;
    private var myImg2:ImageLoader;

    public function Main():void
    {                                   
        myImg1 = new ImageLoader( img1 );
        myImg1.cacheAsBitmap = true;        

        myImg1.addEventListener(ImageLoader.COMPLETE, onImageLoadComplete);     

        addChild( myImg1 );         
    }               

    private function onImageLoadComplete(evt : Event) : void 
    {
        trace (ImageLoader(evt.currentTarget).getWidth());
        trace (ImageLoader(evt.currentTarget).getHeight());
    }

}
```

}

`package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.Loader;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;`

```
public class ImageLoader extends Sprite
{
    private var loader:Loader;
    private var iWidth:int;
    private var iHeight:int;        

    public static const COMPLETE : String = "complete";

    public function ImageLoader( name:String ):void
    {               
        loader = new Loader();          
        loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener( Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler );

        var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest( name );

        loader.load( request );
    }

    public function getWidth():int
    {
        return iWidth;
    }

    public function getHeight():int
    {
        return iHeight;
    }

    private function completeHandler( event:Event ):void
    {   
                    iWidth = event.target.content.width
        iHeight = event.target.content.height;

                    /* dispatcher MUST be after dimension computations */       
        dispatchEvent(new Event(ImageLoader.COMPLETE));

        this.addChild( loader.content );
    }       
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the width and height of the image using the ImageLoader object public functions `getWidth` and `getHeight` but you need to know when the load is complete, so you could dispatch a event from ImageLoader completeHandler, like:

```
// declare public static constant
public static const COMPLETE : String = "complete";
// inside complete handler
dispatchEvent(new Event(ImageLoader.COMPLETE));
```

done with this you can now listen to this event from your Main class like this:

```
myImg2 = new ImageLoader( img2 );
myImg2.addEventListener(ImageLoader.COMPLETE, onImageLoadComplete);

// inside onImageLoadComplete handler you can read the width and height:
private function loadComplete(evt : Event) : void 
{
    trace (ImageLoader(evt.currentTarget).getWidth());
    trace (ImageLoader(evt.currentTarget).getHeight());
}
```

Comment: i did exactly what you suggested but i get 0 and 0 as a result. I updated the code in my first post to be sure i embed your code correctly.

Comment: Yes i found my error!! i had to put the dispatch statement after the computations of width and height. Thanks dome!

Comment: Actually, i can't make any progress on my main work yet because i cannot use these values (width, height) in my Main constructor body. When i try to save the values in onImageLoadComplete to variables and use them in constructor i still get 0 as result :(

Comment: the constructor of your Main class is the first code to be executed so it seams to me logic that those values are not updated yet. So as far as I can see the order that things get executed in your code would be: | 1-> Main (constructor) | 2-> ImageLoad (created inside Main constructor) | 3-> load image | 4-> ImageLoad.completeHandler (here there is the dispatchEvent(new Event(ImageLoader.COMPLETE))) |5-> Main.loadComplete.

So the values you expect are only available where the loadComplete function fires, long time after the constructor of the Main class being executed.